Plotting a power function on a logarithmic scale
I am trying to build and plot an nls model and having problems with defining starting values, and with plotting it on a graph on a log x-axis.
building the nls model:
a <- 5
b <- 2
c <- 3

x <- seq(1, 100, by = 1)

set.seed(123)
noise <- rnorm(length(X), mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
y <- a * x^(-b) + c + noise

df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

c.0 <- min(df$y) * 0.5
model.0 <- lm(log(y - c.0) ~ x, data=df)
start <- list(a=exp(coef(model.0)[1]), b=coef(model.0)[2], c=c.0)

nls_model <- nls(y ~ a * x^(b) + c, data = df,  start= start)

putting in the start values by start = start returns: Error... singular gradient.
putting in the actual start values by start= c(a=1.8095,b=-0.00155959,c=1.385)  returns: Error... Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model.
With other datasets, exactly the same code did create an nls model succesfully. So I am trying to understand what produces the infinity value, and why doesn't it work in some cases?
The second question is about plotting data in a model that could fit a model: Plotting other data with the x-axis on a linear scale creates this:

and with the x-axis on a logarithmic scale, it creates this:

The code that I used to plot these is as follows, but with another dataframe:
ggplot(df, aes(y=y,x=x))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y ~ a * x^(-b)+c, se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(start= c(a=10,b=.1,c=.1)), color = 'red') +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1000,100,10,1))+
  # coord_trans(x = "log10")+
  annotate("text",x=1000,y=45, label = eq_label, parse = TRUE)+
  labs(x="x",y="y")

So I am not sure, but I think it might be that the line in the logarithmic plot is actually true to the model, but because the power of the model itself is lower than the power of the axis transformation it seems like the slope is decreasing. However, is there still a way to create this line on a logarithmic x-axis in a way that is more presentable?

I think your choice of x range is hurting you in this case. given the -2b exponent; if you shorten the x range from up to 100 to up to 10, it works.

adding to my previous comment, you can increase fit accuracy by increasing the density in the range, i.e. step up x by 0.1 instead of 1. but you will need to use nls nls.control to set minFactor, I found  2^(-18) works for your example

Your model is partially linear. Utilize that:
start <- list(b=coef(model.0)[2])

nls_model <- nls(y ~ cbind(a = x^b, c = 1), 
   data = df, start= start, algorithm = "plinear")
coef(nls_model)
#        b    .lin.a    .lin.c 
#-1.936556  4.931716  3.007224

plot(y ~ x, data = df, log = "x")
curve(predict(nls_model, newdata = data.frame(x = x)), 
   add = TRUE, n = 1e4)

Your plotting issue is just a result of not evaluating enough points within stat_smooth. The linear interpolation between points is causing this. Just increase n from the default (as I have done within curve above).


That works, thank you! How do I interpret this: nls(y ~ cbind(a = x^b, c = 1)?

Each column of the matrix is a linear term. The formula means y ~ .lin.a * (x^b) + .lin.c * 1.
